# Mysql subquery not working properly with comma-separated value in column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table **Mapdetail** that has resultTypeIds column storing a comma separated list of ids:

**MapDetails**

```
=============================
mapheaderid     |    resultTypeIds
=============================
54              |    1,4,-9999
```

Now, when I try it as a subquery, it does not return me the correct result while if I hard-code (1,4,-9999) it works fine

**WRONG - RETURNING 1 ROW ONLY**

```
select * from resulttypes rt where rt.resulttypeid in
        (select md1.resulttypeids from mapdetail md1                
            where md1.mapheaderid = 54)
```

**CORRECT - RETURNING 2 ROWS**

```
select * from resulttypes rt where rt.resulttypeid in (1,4,-9999)
```

Comment: It looks like you're assuming '1,4,-9999' will be interpreted in your subquery as multiple values. It is not. It is a single varchar value. You shouldn't store multiple values like this in a single field.

Comment: it is the structure of a legacy database so how can i go around..do i have to split all these values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't re-structure your DB (as mentioned in Comments). Try using `FIND_IN_SET` instead of `IN`

Try something like:

```
select * from resulttypes rt where FIND_IN_SET (rt.resulttypeid,
            (select md1.resulttypeids from mapdetail md1                
            where md1.mapheaderid = 54))
```

Comment: To add to above this will only run when the subquery is returning single record